# Origin of the phrase "fire away"?

Tags: etymology

The phrase "Fire Away", meaning "Ask me questions", appears to be a metaphor stemming from an old military term involving discharging firearms ([source](http://books.google.com/books?id=9re1vfFh04sC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=origin%20%22fire%20away%22&source=bl&ots=JHXFtA9gZp&sig=d_VLJPPIc7vhCTPiYeUuGqUyRjc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S5f-UKzLEY_4qAHCwIGQBg&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=origin%20%22fire%20away%22&f=false)). However, "Away" is generally a directional term, yet in the phrase "Fire away" it seems to mean "at will" or "with abandon". How did it get such an unusual meaning? Was this a sarcastic instruction perhaps?

Comment: It's just an easy metaphor, not sarcastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read "fire away" almost the same way that I would "bombs away", as an order to "release" the projectile, not a suggestion for where they can *put* their projectiles. A longer form might have been "let the fire be away" or "let the fire be on its way". This has the feeling of something that could be an actual order as opposed to an order to whiff, which militaries tend not to do for reasons involving accidental murdering.

Comment: -1 *Bombs away* is not an order to release the bombs; it is a notification that the bombs have been released. The *away* in *bombs away* refers to their position. They are away from the bomber. The *away* in *fire away* and *ask away* refers to motion.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/brewers/fire-away.html

> Say on; say what you have to say. The allusion to firing a gun; as, You are primed up to the muzzle with something you want to say; fire away and discharge your thoughts.
>
> “Foster, I have something I want you and Miss Caryll to understand.” “Fire away!” exclaimed Foster. — Watson: *The Web of a Spider,* chap. xv.
>
> Fire away, Flanagan.
>   A taunt to a boaster. A man threatening you, says he will do this, that, and the other; you reply, “Fire away, Flanagan.” Cromwell marched against a castle defended by Flanagan, who threatened to open his cannon on the Parliamentarians unless they withdrew. Cromwell wrote on the corner of the missive sent to him, “Fire away, Flanagan,” and the doughty champion took to his heels immediately.
>
> Source: Dictionary of Phrase and Fable, E. Cobham Brewer, 1894

The phrase "Fire Away", meaning to go ahead and "Ask me questions" means to *go ahead do your worst*

Comment: He knows that's the current meaning, he wants to know the origin.

Answer (score 0):

> fire away
>
> used to **give someone permission to begin speaking**,
> typically to ask questions:
>
> A: I want to clear up some questions which have been puzzling me.
>
> B: Fire away.

Imagine yourself being a **Glock 19**

[image: GUN!!!!!]

and your words (or your questions) are **bullets**.

Do you want to keep the bullets with yourself, or **fire away**?

**NOTES**

> [away](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=away&allowed_in_frame=0)(adv.)  late Old English aweg, earlier on weg "on from this
> (that) place;" see a- (1) + way. Colloquial use for "**without delay**"
> (fire away, also right away) is from earlier sense of "onward in time"
> (16c.). Intensive use (e.g. away back) is American English, first
> attested 1818.

Comment: That last bit seems to be what I'm looking for. Anyone have more information on the use of 'away' to mean 'onward in time'? How would that have been used in a sentence?

Comment: It is common to use "straight away" to mean immediately. Such as, *I'm actually expecting you to upvote my humble answer straight away and accept it.*

Comment: In your handgun discussion, you claim that *away* in *fire away* is being used in the sense "on from this (or that) place, to a distance" but this is contradicted by your quote which says that the *away* in *fire away* is being used in the sense "without delay".

Comment: @GarethRees Not really, I was stating that "asking a question" can be thought of as "firing a bullet". "Fire away" simply means "fire the bullet without delay".